# How many spare tyres are needed?

Tags: problem-solving

I am about to start a $27,000$ km trip. I check the specifications of tyres to use to find that each is good for only $18,000$ km. 
What is the fewest number of spare  tyres I need to take so I can make it home without having to buy any more?

Comment: How many wheels does your vehicle have?

Comment: Rotation of tyres at a set interval. Im stuck but my answer ive come to is 2 spare or 6 tyres all up

Comment: Standard car angryavian (4)

Comment: Where are you trying to go that's 27,000 km?

Comment: You could also rent a car ;)

Comment: I hope people are aware this is a hypothetical. All i need is some help to see if i am doing it right

Comment: @user262154 What have you done so far?

Comment: Rotating tyres every 5400 but it still over uses two tyres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If using a tyre for one km is a unit we will call a tyre-km, how many tyre-km in your trip?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: What happens right after the first $18,000$ kms?